# jQuery Datepicker: User Going to Next Month or Previous Month?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to repopulate the datepicker with custom css after the user either clicks the 'Next' month or the 'Previous' month. I'm tapping into the onChangeMonthYear event but don't know which way the user is going (next month or previous month). Is there anything simple built in that would give me this? If not, what is the simplest solution?

*** Adding code here to clarify Please note that the events will actually come in via server-side and I've just dummied out some data here while I build***

```
 var Event = function(text, className) {
            this.text = text;
            this.className = className;
        };

        var events = {};
        events[new Date("11/12/2012")] = new Event("A Good Day", "yellowDot");
        events[new Date("11/20/2012")] = new Event("Mkay", "blueDot");

        $('#date').datepicker({              
           beforeShowDay: function (date) {
               var event = events[date];
               if(event) {
                   return [true, event.className, event.text];
               }
               else {
                   return [true, '', ''];
               }
           },
           onChangeMonthYear: function () {
               //reload another calendar, past or future?

           }
        });
```

Comment: Can you provide further details on why you have to know the direction of the change? It might help us understand your intent better. As your question stands, I can only suggest binding to `click` events on the `Prev`/`Next` buttons instead of handling `onChangeMonthYear`.

Comment: I am making some dates "clickable" on the calendar. So if the user goes forward I need to go hit some data and bring back that month's appointments to place them on the new month-view. Same applies for previous month.

Comment: Okay, but why do you need the direction of the change to do so? You could just use the newly selected month and year to query the data and update the widget accordingly. Or am I missing something?

Comment: When the 'Next' button is clicked I don't know what the date is, or what month they were on. Or is there a way to tell that? Sorry, not trying to be obtuse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing an [onChangeMonthYear](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onChangeMonthYear) handler function to the datepicker widget. That function will be called with three arguments:

- the newly selected year,
- the newly selected month,
- the datepicker widget instance.

Therefore, you can write something like:

```
onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, widget) {
    reloadCalendar(month, year);
}
```

The widget instance argument is provided as a shortcut to avoid going through the bridge if you want to manipulate the autocomplete widget. For example, should you want to close the datepicker immediately, it allows you to write:

```
widget.hide();
```

Instead of:

```
$(this).datepicker("hide");
```

Answer (score 2):

Datepicker created dynamically, so you should use `.live`

```
$('.ui-datepicker-next').live("click", function() {
  alert(1)
}
```

Comment: You made my day.